# Foreach SQLite row, download file in Terminal

Tags: macos, sqlite, download, terminal

I have an SQLite database full of product image URLs, what I would like to do is download all the images from the cloud on to my desktop for local use.

Is it possible to run an SQLite select and then, within Mac OS X's Terminal, for each product that has an image, download it?

Comment: This sure would be easy to make with a nice scripting language, such as Python. But what operating system do you use? It should also be fairly easy to do with Bash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BlaXpirit was on the right lines however it turned out like this..

```
LIST=`sqlite3 database.db "SELECT image_column FROM image_table"`
for ROW in $LIST
do
wget $ROW
done
```

I think the problem was either the lack of backquotes in BlaXpirit's answer, or the fact that I needed to define a variable for the connection, which i could then loop through.

to check that LIST had been populated i simply echoed it out using `echo $LIST;` before i carried out the for loop to download all the images.

Comment: This does not generalize as image_column being `TEXT`, its values may contain newlines and whitespaces, upon which  the output will be split.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it in Bash, using `sqlite3` and `wget`:

```bash
for f in sqlite3 database.sqlite3 "SELECT image_column FROM image_table"
do
wget $f
done
```

Bash seems to be what the "Terminal" of Mac OS X uses, so it should work for you.

Comment: Thanks, this was along the right lines. Please see my answer, maybe yours would work if the database and statement were contained in backquotes

Comment: @Wezly You can always edit the answer, no need to make another very similar one

Comment: Will next time, added some more to it anyway.